# Unicorn Error - Missing type attribute for dependency 'dataProviderConfiguration'. Specify an assembly-qualified name for your dependency

Tags: unicorn

I'm getting the following error in Sitecore 10.2 when Installing Unicorn

```
Missing type attribute for dependency 'dataProviderConfiguration'. Specify an assembly-qualified name for your dependency.
```

Stack trace

```
 [InvalidOperationException: Missing type attribute for dependency 'dataProviderConfiguration'. Specify an assembly-qualified name for your dependency.]
   Configy.XmlContainerBuilder.GetConfigType(XmlElement dependency) +282
   Configy.XmlContainerBuilder.RegisterConfigTypeInterfaces(XmlElement dependency, IContainer container) +40
   Configy.XmlContainerBuilder.GetContainer(ContainerDefinition definition) +203
   Configy.<GetContainers>d__2.MoveNext() +212
   System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source) +284
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray(IEnumerable`1 source) +90
   Unicorn.Configuration.ConfigyConfigurationProvider.LoadConfigurations() +341
   Unicorn.Configuration.ConfigyConfigurationProvider.get_Configurations() +28
   Unicorn.Data.DataProvider.UnicornSqlServerDataProvider..ctor(String connectionString) +65

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +223
   Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.CreateObject(Type type, Object[] parameters) +119
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +128
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper) +163
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +72
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +703
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromReference(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +170
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper) +116
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +72
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetConstructorParameters(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +161
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +114
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper) +163
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +72
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetInnerObject(XmlNode paramNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +842
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.AssignProperties(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Object obj, Boolean assert, Boolean deferred, IFactoryHelper helper) +545
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper) +326
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +72
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +703
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetDatabase(String name, Boolean assert) +157
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetDatabase(String name) +55
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetDatabases() +121
   Sitecore.Data.SqlServer.SqlServerLinkDataProviderFactory.CreateProvidersForAllDatabases() +161

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) +269
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +146
   Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.CallStaticMethod(String typeName, String methodName, Object[] parameters) +165
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromFactoryMethod(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +534
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper) +91
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +72
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetConstructorParameters(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +161
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +114
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper) +163
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +72
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert) +703
   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.GetLinkDatabase() +36
   Sitecore.DefaultGlobals.Load() +294
   (Object , Object ) +55
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +1268
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists) +236
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
   Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Application_Start() +146
   Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Init(HttpApplication app) +898
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +584
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +168
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +277
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +369

[HttpException (0x80004005): Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +532
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +111
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +724
```

Unicorn's version is 4.1.6.
I used the Unicorn.DataProvider.config for 10.1.
https://github.com/SitecoreUnicorn/Unicorn/releases/tag/4.1.4

Comment: Can you describe when are you getting errors and is this in a standalone instance or CM?

Comment: @GayathriSriram
XP Single (XP0) Instance installed in my local environment.
Error will occur when viewing target host in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.

I was referring to Helix's Unicorn project.
https://github.com/Sitecore/Helix.Examples/tree/master/examples/helix-basic-unicorn

It seems that the problem was the following. In `Foundation.Serialization.Base.config`

```
<dataProviderConfiguration set:enableTransparentSync="$(env:UNICORN_ENABLE_TRANSPARENT_SYNC)" />
```

I deleted here.
Or, add 'type'.
As written in Unicorn.config.

```
<dataProviderConfiguration set:enableTransparentSync="$(env:UNICORN_ENABLE_TRANSPARENT_SYNC)" type="Unicorn.Data.DataProvider.DefaultUnicornDataProviderConfiguration, Unicorn" />
```